# powershell wildcard character in a control file list

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that uses a control file to archive files:

```
# Takes the information from $controlfile and moves the files to the archive folder**

foreach ($line in get-content $controlfile)
{
$file = $controlfile
$split = $line.split("|")
$archive_path = $split[0]
$source_path = $split[1]
$basename = $split[2]
$extention = $split[3]
$daystoleave = $split[4]

# move the files to the archive folder

Get-ChildItem $source_path -Filter "$basename*" -Force -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays($daystoleave)} | Move-Item -Destination $archive_path
Get-ChildItem $archive_path -Filter "$basename*" -Force -Recurse | % { rename-item –path $_.Fullname –Newname (("$basename") + ("_") + ($_.LastWriteTime.toString("MM.dd.yy_HH.mm.ss")) + (".$extension")) }
}
```

Control file example:

\server\Apps\Archive-Requests\|\server\Apps\requests\|?||0

\server\Apps\Archive-Requests\|\server\Apps\requests\|*||0

Above examples don't work because of the ? or * character in the file name split of the control file.

\server\Apps\Archives\Archive_Daily_Reports\|\apps\FICS\Daily Reports\|audit|fics|0

Above example works because "audit" is the beginning of the file name.

This works fine when I want to capture and use the first part of the original file name (ex. SAD123.txt - capture SAD|add LastWriteTime date to name|add extension|leave some file(s) in original folder ($daystoleave).

But if I'd like to capture either the entire original name or a middle portion of the name using wildcard characters, I receive "Illegal characters in path." and nothing changes to the end result filename. Is there a wildcard I can use other than  * or ? in the control file.

Is it possible to use a wildcard in the control file?

Comment: please add to your OP two or three _exact_ samples AND the _exact_ result for each of those lines.

Comment: My real conundrum is "Is it possible to use a wildcard in the control file?"